# Change Boolean values to text in angular 2 client side

Tags: typescript, angular

### Detail

I am trying to get data from api and show into the table on of the column contains status attribute which return true or false value but I want to show on client side Active or Block instead of this. How can I able to achieve this in angular 2.

[image]

Comment: So you have 3 columns for the same thing things. One would be enough.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would suggest a pipe that returns either active or blocked according to the boolean.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'activeBlocked'})
export class ActiveBlockedPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) {
        return value ? 'Active' : 'Blocked';
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this in you components template:

```
{{value | activeBlocked}}
```

In my opinion this is the easiest to reuse.

Comment: Nice response useful to transform any code to a display text.
But it remains one question. How do you support i18n of the returned text (for the moemnt your pipe always returns english text; it will be good to return text for language of current user) ?

Comment: You can inject your i18n service in the pipe and use it for translations

Comment: That is the question : what is i18n service ? According to this issue, the usage of i18n resources outside template is not really available :
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405#issuecomment-268320785.
But the pipe remains a good response for the asked question.

Comment: Mind to add this pipe into the declarations array in the app.module.ts

Answer (score 9):

You could do it directly in the view:

```
<td>{{user.IsActive && 'Active' || 'Block'}}</td>
```

Comment: Need some parenthesis due to order of operations?

Answer (score 7):

> How can I able to achieve this in angular 2

Just use javascript/typescript:

```
const valueFromServer = false; // Assuming
const toShow = valueFromServer ? 'Active' : 'Blocked';
```

Comment: `{{ user.IsActive == true ? 'Active' : 'Block' }}`

Comment: @AhmedJalal You don need the `== true`.

Comment: @AhmedJalal Angular team doesn't recommend using any logic inside template expression: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#simplicity. So it is better to put `user.IsActive ? 'Active' : 'Block'` code inside component or a pipe(as described below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38321811/4956536)

Answer (score 5):

Simple way is use conditional operator inside td element

```
<td>{{user.status ? 'Active' : 'Block'}}</td>
```